# Acessing data form database on click of listView

Tags: android, database, listview

I have a ListView in activity1 where I have a few items which are the word from the database . The User Clicks on an item in the Listview and it will navigate to activity2 where it should show the details of the word which are stored in database as column word, definitions . But What appears in Screen2 depends on what item was clicked in Screen 1

For Ex - User Clicks A in Screen 1 - Words starting from A come up in Screen 2. Is there any way to pass the row id so that in next screen the word and definition from the database can be displayed.

Thank you in adv..
code for first activity:

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Cursor c = mDictCursor;
            c.moveToPosition(position);
            Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            //intent.putExtra("position",position);
            bundle.putLong(DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
            bundle.putString(DBAdapter.KEY_TITLE, c.getString(
                  c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
            bundle.putString(DBAdapter.KEY_DEFINITION, c.getString(
                    c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.KEY_DEFINITION)));
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(i);
        }
```

SecondActivity code:

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

```
        mRowId = extras.getLong(DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
        String title = extras.getString(DBAdapter.KEY_TITLE);
        String body = extras.getString(DBAdapter.KEY_DEFINITION);


        TextView word = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
        word.setText(title);

            TextView definition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definition);
            definition.setText(body);
        }
```

Whenever I am clicking the listview item it is showing dialog to force close. Please help...

Comment: Can you please post logcat error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Intent object putExtra(String name, int value) method in Screen1(see1) and pass the intent object to Screen2,in Screen2 use getIntExtra(String name, int defaultValue) method of Intent object(see 2).
1.use startActivity(Intent intent) method in Screen1
2.use getIntent() method in Screen2 to get Intent object which you passed in the Screen1

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am using the same, but still getting errors. May be I am using them in wrong way. Can u please provide any tutorial or example which I can refer, it will be really useful.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking something similar like this .
https://market.android.com/developer?pub=acharya
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.acharyaapp.malayalam.aksharam.full
(Those are my apps)

Why dont you try using a Singleton class to store information. One Intent can set it and the other intent can read it. I employed that logic in my apps.

**EDIT**

```
public class MySingleton {
    private static final MySingleton INSTANCE = new MySingleton();
    //TODO ... all your variable as public static variables. eg. KEY_TITLE
    private MySingleton() { }
    public static MySingleton getInstance() 
            return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Inside activities, use them as normal instances. Just make sure to call the getInstance() instead of constructor to get the shared instance.

hope this helps.

Comment: @sm added. see above. it is basic singleton. nothing fancy.